# Word Study G3516: νήπιος (nēpios) babes

Tags: word-study, jesus, spiritual-birth, children-of-god

## ***νήπιος (nēpios) - babes***

Jesus used this word twice.

Mat 11:25

> At that time Jesus answered and said, I thank thee, **O Father, Lord of heaven and earth**, because thou hast hid these things from the wise and prudent, and hast revealed them unto ***babes***. G3516

***According to Jesus (who is the only one to use this word in the gospels),... What are the qualities of "babes" who are revealed Truth straight from his God and Father, the "Lord of heaven and earth"***?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular passage, Jesus contrast "babes" to the wise and prudent (also translated as intelligent, clever, understanding). The modern sense of "prudent" is probably not the best translation here. But in any case, we can infer that the qualities of these babes are innocence, trust and even blissful ignorance. A similar thought about God hiding his plan from the wise and clever is expressed more directly by Paul in 1 Cor. 2:

> We speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, the hidden wisdom which God
> ordained before the ages for our glory, which none of the rulers of
> this age knew; for had they known, they would not have crucified the
> Lord of glory. (2 Cor. 7-8)

Each of the Gospels, agreeing with Paul, presents the crucifixion of Jesus are part of God's foreordained plan. If the rulers of the age --those who had "wisdom and prudence" -- had accepted Jesus, this predestined plan would not have gone forward.

The previous verses of Mt. 11 involve Jesus' reacting in sorrow and frustration at his rejection by the chosen people. Thus, after expressing natural human emotion due to his rejection by those seemingly prepared to receive him, **Jesus turns to his Heavenly Father and expresses gratitude that God has hidden Jesus' identity as the Messiah from the wise and prudent, revealing it instead to those of simple faith, who would carry forth the Gospel.**

Answer (score -1):

Jesus says narrow is the way and few find it in this age.  There are few babes to whom the Father reveals His 1 Truth.

Mark 10:15 KJV

> **Verily I say unto you, Whosoever shall not receive the kingdom of God as a little child, he shall not enter therein.**

In the Sermon on the Mount, Jesus details the qualities of those who will inherit the Kingdom to come...the *children of God*.

Matthew 5
King James Version

> <sup>**1**</sup> And seeing the multitudes, he went up into a mountain: and when he was set, his disciples came unto him: <sup>**2**</sup> And he opened his mouth, and taught them, saying,
>
> <sup>**3**</sup> Blessed are the **poor in spirit**: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.
>
> <sup>**4**</sup> Blessed are **they that mourn**: for they shall be comforted.
>
> <sup>**5**</sup> Blessed are the **meek**: for they shall inherit the earth.
>
> <sup>**6**</sup> Blessed are **they which do hunger and thirst after righteousness**: for they shall be filled.
>
> <sup>**7**</sup> Blessed are the **merciful**: for they shall obtain mercy.
>
> <sup>**8**</sup> Blessed are the **pure in heart**: for they shall see God.
>
> <sup>**9**</sup> Blessed are the **peacemakers**: for they shall be called the children of God.
>
> <sup>**10**</sup> Blessed are **they which are persecuted for righteousness' sake**: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.
>
> <sup>**11**</sup> Blessed are **ye, when men shall revile you**, and persecute you, and shall say all manner of evil against you falsely, **for my sake**. <sup>**12**</sup> Rejoice, and be exceeding glad: for great is your reward in heaven: for so persecuted they the prophets which were before you.
>
> <sup>**13**</sup> Ye are the **salt of the earth**: but if the salt have lost his savour, wherewith shall it be salted? it is thenceforth good for nothing, but to be cast out, and to be trodden under foot of men.
>
> <sup>**14**</sup> Ye are the **light of the world**. A city that is set on an hill cannot be hid. <sup>**15**</sup> Neither do men light a candle, and put it under a bushel, but on a candlestick; and it giveth light unto all that are in the house. <sup>**16**</sup> Let your light so shine before men, that they may see your good works, and glorify your Father which is in heaven.